# Google Adsense ad showing on same pages my website but not on other page at same website

Tags: php, css, html, adsense, html4

Thank you for giving you time.
I have google adsense approve account.
i try to add those code on my other website.
the ad are showing on same page of website but not other page.
What happen i dont know.

**showing ad on website link** http://marathwadaneta.uuid.in/news/1#sthash.qW4111wP.P6PXeudF.dpbs

**Ad not showing same website**: [website](http://marathwadaneta.uuid.in)

Comment: How long ago was the account approved and ad unit created? It can take a while for ads to show up

Comment: Account has 1year complete and ad unit 6month

Comment: can any one not able to give my question anser???